# Calling an interface method on all instances from a static method

Tags: java, interface

I am not sure how to do this or if it is possible. Basically I am writing my own gui system and I want an interface to handle click detection. The gui elements (`GuiButton`, etc.) are all subclassess of `GuiElement`. What I want is to be able to statically call `GuiElement.onCLick(x,y)` and then have all of the child class instances of this class to fire their overwritten `OnCLickListener` interface.

Basically I don't want to have to keep a reference of every element and loop through it.

Comment: You might not want that, but that's what you'd have to do.

Comment: Not gonna work, and probably an indication that you need to redesign your application a bit.

Comment: @Guillaume: No, don't encourage link-sending!  If there's a relevant example, the OP should post the code directly into their question.

Comment: If you have some code, please add it to your question, we will have a look at it. (comment updated on the remark of @Oli)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are writing your own GUI as an exercise.

The comment is right, you might not want to keep a reference to all instances of `GuiElement`, but you have to. More than that, you probably do not want to have a static call to `GuiElement.onClick(x, y)`. Static call like this are a code smell ... And even more, you probably do not want to propagate mouse click to all `GuiElement`, but only to `GuiElements` that are positioned at `(x, y)`.

You should probably have a look at how [`MouseEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html) is defined in Swing. Even if Swing has a few drawbacks, most of its base concepts are sound. Studying how it was implemented will give you a few pointer in the right direction. Writing your own GUI layer is a very good exercise, it is a very good playground to object oriented design, but some reading will help you a long way in that direction.

Comment: or he could just use Swing, but in his post he said he is "writing his own gui system.."